# dynamic tooltips in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-datatable

I 've created an angular sample app which includes ngx-datatable component [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6immo). I've added the same tooltip in first column for each cell. Everytime you push the button in first column you copy the text and I want to change tooltip's text to "copied" dynamically. Could you check it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the row's index on click for example and change the text accordingly if current row matches.

I forked and edit your example to illustrate https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygrjbj?file=src/app/demo-component.ts